# Latex Plot wrong Graph

Tags: latex, tikz

You guys have an idea why latex plots the wrong function?

This is my function:

```
     \draw [scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\x] plot (\x,0.5*\x^4 - 3*\x^2+ 4) node[right] {$f(x)=0.5*x^4 - 3*x^2 + 4$};
```

and this is the result:
[Latex Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiWvj.png)

But is should look like this:
[Right Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y9AQ.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `tikz`, parentheses are required to properly square negative numbers.

```
\draw [scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\x] plot (\x,{0.5*(\x)^4 - 3*(\x)^2+ 4}) node[right] {$f(x)=0.5*x^4 - 3*x^2 + 4$};
```

This should produce what 
[you wanted](https://artofproblemsolving.com/texer/nbhkqcid).